# TFS build keep everything but revision number

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-process-template

I need to create a build definition for branches so they have the major version, minor version and build number kept, but with an auto increment of the revision number.

My project uses a .Proj file and the UpgradeTemplatr.xaml business process template.

How can I change the version strategy?

Answer (score 0):

in the build definition, under Adavanced > Build Number Format you can enter a string for the format, you can use the macro tool to poulate it with data. the standard one i use is shown below. it will produce Build_1.0.2014192.revision today(11/07/2014)

$(BuildDefinitionName)_1.0.$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(Rev:.r)

you could use:

$(BuildDefinitionName)_1.0.0(Rev:.r)

and then replace 1.0.0 with the version number you want to use, this will give you fixed values with the Revision number changing with each build.

Comment: I'm using the UpgradeTemplate.xaml, it doesn't have a Build Number Format option.